# Making a personal loan to my business from the proceeds of cashing out my 401k

Tags: united-states, 401k, loans, tax-deduction, small-business

I had to cash out my 401k and lent the proceeds to my graphic design business to keep it afloat. It was used replace a computer and to pay off business debt. Total loan is $22,000.  We had a promissory note drawn up at a current loan rate of 3.3% with a payback upon demand, and not later than 3 years from the date of the loan.  Because it is money I lent to the S Corp, do I have to declare it as income too, or only when the company pays it back?

Comment: Should there be a tag for tales of woe?

Comment: Pete, a little bit of snark here?  I was hoping this was a forum that wold answer questions and help without inuendo.

Answer (score 5):

The principal of the loan itself isn't any sort of taxable event.  There are, however, two taxable events here.

First, cashing out your 401(k).  That income wasn't originally taxed, so it will be now, as regular income.  Plus, you're going to pay a 10% penalty, assuming you're under 59.5 years of age.

Second, *when the business pays you interest*, that interest will be taxable.  The principal is not taxable; that's not income, after all. You simply are getting back what's yours.  The interest is taxable, as that is the actual income here.